# Is there a way to CASE DD-MMM-YYYY date format?

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I am trying to case a column that has a date format of DD-MMM-YYYY.

Basically, I am trying to convert the dates into a Fiscal Year column to better analyze work data.
I can't share the actual data here due to privacy issues. Below is my syntax.

> I get the ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got CHAR.

The TRAVEL_DT column is a DATE data type.

```
Select Lst_name, frst_nm, travel_date,
       case when TRAVEL_DT <= '30-SEP-2020' THEN 'FY-2019'
            WHEN TRAVEL_DT >= '01-OCT-2020' THEN 'FY-2020'
            ELSE TRAVEL_DT
       END AS FISCAL_YEAR
FROM TRAVEL_DATA
```

Comment: Either use a proper date literal, or go with the to_date function.

Comment: @jarlh, how do I do this? my apology, but I am a novice at this.

Comment: I'd try `TRAVEL_DT <= DATE'2020-09-30'`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [oracle convert DD-MON-YY to DD/MM/YYYY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40224008/oracle-convert-dd-mon-yy-to-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: Another problem is that your case expression has incompatible return data types. 'FY-2019' and 'FY-2020' are character, but TRAVEL_DT is a date. You probably need to do to_char on the date.

Comment: @jarlh, TRAVEL_DT <= DATE'2020-09-30' --- this didn't work

Comment: @jarlh, how do I do a to_char on the date? I am trying to keep the DD-MMM-YYYY format because my internal clients prefer it this way.

Comment: I'd check month and return "FY prior year" if month is less than October, otherwise "FY year".

Comment: _" I am a novice at this"_  The first thing you need to do is firmly fix in your mind the difference between a date and a string of characters that a human recognizes as representing a date.  In reality, a date is just a concept.  In oracle, it is properly stored as data type DATE and is a binary structure with no human-recongizable format.   Cont . . .

Comment: . . . continuing .... What is the data type of your column TRAVEL_DT?  If it is not DATE, then you have a serious design flaw.  The statement "when TRAVEL_DT <= '30-SEP-2020'", the '30-SEP-2020' (enlcosed in single quotes) is not a date, but a character string, and it will be compared, collated, and sorted as such.  So '01-APR-2021' would come before '30-SEP-2020'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `case` returns text in the `when` clauses and a date in the `else`. Try this:

```
Select Lst_name, frst_nm, travel_date,
       case when TRAVEL_DT <= '30-SEP-2020' THEN 'FY-2019'
            WHEN TRAVEL_DT >= '01-OCT-2020' THEN 'FY-2020'
            ELSE to_char(TRAVEL_DT)
       END AS FISCAL_YEAR
FROM TRAVEL_DATA
```

Comment: This will fail if the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter is not an equivalent of `DD-MON-YYYY` as it relies on implicit string-to-date conversions. It would be better to use date literals. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f164d94c0ab0f552425f9fc06bbfdb20)

Answer (score 0):

To get the date at the start of the fiscal year you can:

- Subtract 9 months;
- truncate to the start of the year; and then
- add 9 months again

If you just want to know the fiscal year then:

- Subtract 9 months;
- extract the year.

Like this:

```sql
Select Lst_name,
       frst_nm,
       travel_dt,
       'FY-' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS(travel_dt, -9)) AS fiscal_year,
       ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(travel_dt,-9),'YY'),9) AS start_of_fiscal_year
FROM TRAVEL_DATA
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE travel_data (lst_name, frst_nm, travel_dt) AS
SELECT 'Abbot', 'Alice', DATE '2020-09-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Baron', 'Betty', DATE '2020-10-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Curry', 'Carol', DATE '2019-10-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Doyle', 'Doris', DATE '2021-09-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Eagle', 'Emily', DATE '2021-10-01' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | LST_NAME | FRST_NM | TRAVEL_DT | FISCAL_YEAR | START_OF_FISCAL_YEAR |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Abbot | Alice | 2020-09-30 00:00:00 | FY-2019 | 2019-10-01 00:00:00 |
> | Baron | Betty | 2020-10-01 00:00:00 | FY-2020 | 2020-10-01 00:00:00 |
> | Curry | Carol | 2019-10-01 00:00:00 | FY-2019 | 2019-10-01 00:00:00 |
> | Doyle | Doris | 2021-09-30 00:00:00 | FY-2020 | 2020-10-01 00:00:00 |
> | Eagle | Emily | 2021-10-01 00:00:00 | FY-2021 | 2021-10-01 00:00:00 |

---

If you just want to fix your code then you can use date literals:

```sql
Select Lst_name,
       frst_nm,
       travel_dt,
       CASE
       WHEN TRAVEL_DT <  DATE '2020-10-01' THEN 'FY-2019'
       WHEN TRAVEL_DT >= DATE '2020-10-01' THEN 'FY-2020'
       END AS FISCAL_YEAR
FROM   TRAVEL_DATA
```

*Note: You do not need the `ELSE` condition as it will only ever be matched when `TRAVEL_DT` is `NULL`.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=072bc8730e4bb0d0576d14b44addac98)*